# Как в рамках одной формы, сложить значение value и data-* и вывести их в разные инпуты

Tags: javascript, jquery

Сделал вот такую форму, написал скрипт который складывает значения value у селектов и выдаёт их общее значение в input с тегом result, подскажите пожалуйста каким образом можно сложить значение атрибутов data, с дальнейшим выводом суммы в input с тегом resultTwo это должно быть просто, но у меня почему-то не выходит

```
<section class="section">
        < form>
            <select>
                <option selected disabled>Выберите пункт...</option>
                <option value="1" data-n="1">1</option>
                <option value="2" data-n="2">2</option>
                <option value="3" data-n="3">3</option>
            </select>
            <select>
                <option selected disabled>Выберите пункт...</option>
                <option value="4" data-n="4">1</option>
                <option value="5" data-n="5">2</option>
                <option value="6" data-n="6">3</option>
            </select>
            <select>
                <option selected disabled>Выберите пункт...</option>
                <option value="7" data-n="7">1</option>
                <option value="8" data-n="8">2</option>
                <option value="9" data-n="9">3</option>
            </select>
        <input class="d-block res" type="text" value="0" id="result">
        <input class="d-block res" type="text" value="0" id="resultTwo">
```

Comment: А где скрипт то?

Answer (score 0):

вы можете достать значение data с помощью dataset.n , n это название data после -